# Haskell GHC: Failed to load interface for 'Test.QuickCheck'

Tags: haskell, ghc, quickcheck

[image: a ghci error]

So I have to include the **'Test.QuickCheck'** library for some testings for a subject. Although I've use it the whole year, I reinstalled **GHC/GHCi** recently and **it doesn't load this library**. The other functions work as planned. Currently using Xubuntu 16.04.

Do you have any idea of what might be the error?

Comment: Did you try to *Use `-v' to see a list of the files searched for* to try and see what ghci is doing instead of importing that module? Also: it is a **terrible** idea to post *pictures* of *text* (e.g. code and error messages). blind people cannot see those, and also you are making the question un-searchable. Always prefer to copy &paste the error message and code into the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `stack`.

```
stack install QuickCheck
```

That will add it to the global config in `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`

Better yet, set up a new project with `stack new` and add `QuickCheck` in the build-depends section of your `[projectname].cabal` file.